# Filter by clustering fields using a sub-select query

Tags: google-bigquery

With Google Bigquery, I am querying a clustered table by applying a filter on the clustering field `projectId`, like so:

```
WITH userProjects AS (

    SELECT 
        projectsArray 
    FROM 
        projectsPerUser 
    WHERE 
        userId = "eben@somewhere.com"
)

SELECT 
    userProperty
FROM 
    `mydata.mydataset.mytable`
WHERE 
    --projectId IN UNNEST((SELECT projectsArray FROM userProjects))
    projectId IN ("mydata", "anotherproject")
    AND _PARTITIONTIME >= "2019-03-20"
```

Clustering is applied correctly in the code snippet above, but when I use the commented-out line `--projectId IN UNNEST((SELECT projectsArray FROM userProjects))`, clustering doesn't apply.

I've tried wrapping it in a UDF like this as well, which also doesn't work:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION storedValue(item ARRAY<STRING>) AS (
  item
);

...

WHERE projectId IN UNNEST(storedValue((SELECT projectsListArray FROM projectsList)))
```

As I understand from this, the execution path for sub-select queries is different to merely filtering on a scalar or array directly.

I expect a solution to exist where I can programmatically supply an array to filter on that will still allow me the cost benefit a clustered table provides.

In summary:

1. `WHERE projectId IN ("mydata", "anotherproject")` [OK]
2. `WHERE projectId IN UNNEST((SELECT projectsArray FROM userProjects))` [Not OK]
3. `WHERE projectId IN UNNEST(storedValue((SELECT projectsListArray FROM projectsList)))` [Not OK]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to rewrite your query so that your nested SELECT is a temporary table (which you've already done) and then perform the filtering you require by using an INNER JOIN rather than a set membership test, so your query would become something like this:

```
WITH userProjects AS (

    SELECT 
        projectsArray 
    FROM 
        projectsPerUser 
    WHERE 
        userId = "eben@somewhere.com"
)

SELECT 
    userProperty
FROM 
    `mydata.mydataset.mytable` as a
    JOIN
    userProjects as b
    ON a.projectId = b.projectsArray
WHERE 
    AND _PARTITIONTIME >= "2019-03-20"
```

I believe this will result in a query which does not scan the full partition if that field is clustered.

Comment: This is great Daniel!  Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, clustering works well for me with dynamic filters:

```
SELECT title, SUM(views) views
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019`
WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(datehour, DAY)) = '2019-01-01'
AND wiki='en'
AND title IN ('Dogfight_(disambiguation)','Dogfight','Dogfight_(film)')
GROUP BY 1

1.8 sec elapsed, 364 MB processed
```

if instead I do

```
AND title IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT prev 
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_vt.clickstream_materialized` 
  WHERE date='2019-01-01' AND prev LIKE 'Dogfight%'
  ORDER BY 1  LIMIT 3)

2.9 sec elapsed, 513.8 MB processed
```

If I go to v2 (not clustered), instead of v3:

```
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2019`

2.6 sec elapsed, 9.6 GB processed
```

I'm not sure what's happening in your tables - but it might be interesting to revisit.